# Get top n records from each of 5 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2016, I have 5 large tables. What's the best way to select the top 1000 records from each of the 5 tables in one query?

This for example returns too much data.

```
Select * 
from table1 
cross apply table2
cross apply table3 
cross apply table4 
cross apply table5 with(nolock)
```

Also, I was looking to get every column from each of the 5 tables..but just the first 1000 rows from each table.

Comment: Side point: why do you have `with(nolock)` what do you think it does to your query?

Comment: default transaction isolation level is the READ COMMITTED isolation level, in which retrieving the changing data will be blocked until these changes are committed. The WITH (NOLOCK) table hint is used to override the default transaction isolation level of the table or the tables within the view in a specific query, by allowing the user to retrieve the data without being affected by the locks

Comment: Top 1000 rows... in which order?

Comment: I presume you are also aware that it can return *completely* incorrect results, including but not limited to: reading rows or even whole pages twice or not at all, reading data that fails unique or foreign key constraints, or even check constraints, rows which are meant to be unique causing joins to double up, can cause "data has moved" errors, and so on. It's the wrong solution for almost any problem involving locks: if you have concurrent writers, use `SNAPSHOT`. If there are no concurrent writers then what are you worried about anyway? At the most you could just do `TABLOCK` for performance

Comment: See also these articles https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere and https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/08/but-nolock-is-okay-when-the-data-isnt-changing-right/ and https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/quaere-verum-clustered-index-scans-part-iii and this one from an actual Microsoft emplyee https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/281562/220697

Comment: If we assume that each table has 10 columns, do you expect a resultset of 5000 rows containing 10 columns or one of 1000 rows containing 50 columns?

Comment: Cross apply gives you every possible combination of rows from each table. So if you select a table with 5 rows cross applied with a table that has 4 rows, you get 20 rows as a result. Even if you were limiting the number of rows from each table to 1000, your query would return 1,000,000,000,000,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `CROSS APPLY`.

Note: If you have just one query, you have just one result set. A result set must have a well-defined list of columns. Thus, you must tell SQL Server which of your columns in those different tables are "equal", by putting them in the same position.

Example:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 a, b, c FROM table1 ORDER BY d
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1000 x, y, z FROM table2 ORDER BY w
UNION ALL
...
```

In this case, the data types of `a` and `x` must be compatible, same for `b` and `y`, etc.

The column names from the very first SELECT statement (`a`, `b` and `c` in this example) will be used as the column names of the result set.

Comment: hm. i had tried union all but got this message. All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.. the columns aren't the same in all 5 tables and not necessarily similar data types.

Comment: @tonys777: If they have different types of columns, how do you want to combine them into 1 result set?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about them being the same result set, just one query that returns all of them, you can just make 5 separate select statements in 1 query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM table1
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM table2
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM table3
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM table4
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM table5
```

If for some reason you need to have them in a single result set, including a row number column then joining them on the row number might work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [orderCol]) AS RN, * FROM table1) AS T1
JOIN (SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [orderCol]) AS RN, * FROM table2) AS T2 ON T1.RN = T2.RN
JOIN (SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [orderCol]) AS RN, * FROM table3) AS T3 ON T1.RN = T3.RN
JOIN (SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [orderCol]) AS RN, * FROM table4) AS T4 ON T1.RN = T4.RN
JOIN (SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [orderCol]) AS RN, * FROM table5) AS T5 ON T1.RN = T5.RN
```